# Triggering Bash Before Killed

Tags: shell-script, kill

I just made some kind of service code.
Check this out:

```sh
do_start() {
    while true
    do
        if [[ $(pgrep -fl loopsvn.sh | wc -l) -gt 2 ]]; then
            echo "Already use by another process..."
            exit
        else
            echo "Press [Ctrl+C] to stop..."
            sleep 1
        fi
    done
}

do_stop() {
    killall loopsvn.sh
}
```

My question, how can I start some other process before it is killed?
My plan was like this:

```sh
do_restart() {
     cat loopsvn.sh > svntmp.sh
     chmod +x svntmp.sh
     do_kill
     exec svntmp.sh #HOW CAN I DO THIS LINE AFTER do_kill
}
```

this script is one-instance process, so after kill, it triggers other script to execute.

Comment: pgrep has a `-c` (count) option too, will return number of PID's found.  You wouldn't need to pipe through `wc`.  Read the [man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep).

Comment: I don't understand the question: what does `do_kill` do? Your script does run `exec svntmp.sh` after running `do_kill` (unless `do_kill` kills the running script, in which case the solution is obviously not to do that), so what are you trying to do?

Comment: ohh sorry my mistakes, it should be do_stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xterm -e "bash -c \"./script.sh; exec bash\"" &`

where `./script.sh` can be just a command.

Comment: Thank you very much :), but where I suppose to put that code? After kill? or before kill?

Comment: Before kill I think, because the execution of this code will lunch `script.sh` in a different terminal which will live even if you kill your current terminal.